# Marble Diagrams

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

The Marble diagrams are frequently from the Rx team explaining how certain operators in Rx work. Are there any tool to create the marble diagrams?

[image: marble diagram]

Comment: VisualRx ... http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2012/08/12/visual-rx-toc.aspx

Comment: RxMarbles is heading that way but you can't do custom operators yet. http://rxmarbles.com/

Answer (score 3):

I've thought about creating a tool like this a fair bit having created quite a few of them in Visio (look on my [blog](http://www.zerobugbuild.com) for examples). I looked around to see if anyone else had done it and couldn't find anything terribly useful. At first blush, it seemed like an obvious tool to write - but I think almost every useful (i.e. complex/interesting) scenario I've worked with has required a uniquely "human" approach to diagram sensibly.